# Need help implementing a pop up to show an ArrayList on a flight arrivals map in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I have been trying to create a flight arrivals map program using windowbuilder however I have been stuck on displaying in the incoming flights for each airport

For context this map[ should display incoming flights when you hover your mouse on the letters(i.e hovering on YYZ will display incoming flight arrivals for Toronto airport)
I have an  set of ArrayLists from a java file. Lets call it Aeroports.java which scans a csv file and scans it adding a line into a certain arraylist depending on its airport code(e.g YYZFlights)
The CSV file is in the format
DateOfFlight[0],DepartureTime[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLaoK.png),ArrivalTime[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJdo.png),FlightDuration[3]

I have posted the full code below. I had to change the format of the dat so it could be read

Below is the program which stores the setters(procedures) and getters(functions) for each object

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Flights {
    private String flightNo;
    private String departureCity;
    private String departureAirport;
    private String ArrivalAirport;
    private int delayedTime;
    private LocalTime newArrivalTime;
    private LocalTime ArrivalTime;
    private LocalTime departureTime;
    private LocalDate FlightDate;

    
    public void setFlightNo(String flightNo)///sets the flightNo for each object
    {
        this.flightNo = flightNo;
    }
    public String getFlightNo()
    {
        return flightNo;
    }
    public void setdepartureCity(String departureCity)///sets the departure city for each object
    {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }
    public String getdepartureCity()
    {
        return departureCity;
    }
    public void setdepartureAirport(String departureAirport)///sets the departure airport for each object
    {
        this.departureAirport = departureAirport;
    }
    public String getdepartureAirport()
    {
        return departureAirport;
    }
    public void setdelayedTime(int delayedTime)
    {
        this.delayedTime = delayedTime;
    }
    public int getdelayedTime()
    {
        return delayedTime;
    }
    public void setnewArrivalTime(LocalTime newArrivalTime)
    {
        this.newArrivalTime = newArrivalTime;
        
    }
    public LocalTime getnewArrivalTime()
    {
        return newArrivalTime;
        
    }
    public void setArrivalTime(LocalTime newArrivalTime)
    {
        this.ArrivalTime = newArrivalTime;
        
    }
    public LocalTime getArrivalTime()
    {
        return ArrivalTime;
        
    }
    public void setdepartureTime(LocalTime departureTime)
    {
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
    }
    public LocalTime getdepartureTime()
    {
        return departureTime;
    }
    public void setArrivalAirport(String ArrivalAirport)
    {
        this.ArrivalAirport = ArrivalAirport;
    }
    public String getArrivalAirport()
    {
        return ArrivalAirport;
    }
    public void setFlightDate( LocalDate FlightDate)
    {
        this.FlightDate = FlightDate;
        
    }
    public LocalDate getFlightDate( )
    {
        return FlightDate;
        
    }
}
```

Listed below is the main program where delayed flights are calculated for each object and stores the ArrayLists that I intend to use in the future

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.time.*;
public class BCLAirport {
    static ArrayList<Flights> allFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> alldelayedFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> BCLFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();///Array list for Airport with code BCL the ones for the others are listed below
    static ArrayList<Flights> SYDFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> DXBFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> DELFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> BKKFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> DUBFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> CDGFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> GRUFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> YYZFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> JFKFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> MEXFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> ARNFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> CAIFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> LOSFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> AMSFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> LVSFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> DFWFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> JNBFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> HNDFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> SVOFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> LISFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> MADFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> RAKFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> ATHFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    static ArrayList<Flights> FCOFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();
    public static void mainrun() throws ParseException ///
    {
    try
    {
        File myObj = new File("C:/Flights.csv"//this leads to flight csv file imagine this in a format); //Scans for the csv file
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);///gets input of csv file
        
        while (myReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] data = myReader.nextLine().split(",");///splits the line by the commas
            
            Flights Flights = new Flights();//creayes new object
            Flights.setdepartureAirport(data[6]);///sets the departure airport
            Flights.setdepartureCity(data[7]);/// sets the departure city
            Flights.setFlightNo(data[10]);//sets the flight number
            Flights.setdelayedTime(Integer.parseInt(data[5]));// sets the delayed time
            Flights.setdepartureTime(LocalTime.parse(data[1]));///sets the departure Time
            Flights.setArrivalAirport(data[8]);
            Flights.setArrivalTime(LocalTime.parse(data[2]));
            
            String[] dating = data[0].split("/");
            String newdating = dating[2]+"-"+dating[1]+"-"+dating[0];
            data[0]=newdating;//writes the date in the new format
            LocalDate todaysDate = LocalDate.now();
            Flights.setFlightDate(LocalDate.parse(data[0]));
            int delayTime = Integer.parseInt(data[5]);/// integer for the delayed time in minutes
            if (LocalDate.parse(newdating).equals(todaysDate)) {
                System.out.println("yes");
            
            if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "BCL") {///Array lists for each airport
                BCLFlights.add(Flights);
            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "SYD") {
                SYDFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "DXB") {
                DXBFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "DEL") {
                DELFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "BKK") {
                BKKFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "DUB") {
                DUBFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "CDG") {
                CDGFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "GRU") {
                GRUFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "YYZ") {
                YYZFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "JFK") {
                JFKFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "MEX") {
                MEXFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "ARN") {
                ARNFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "CAI") {
                CAIFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "LOS") {
                LOSFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "AMS") {
                AMSFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "LVS") {
                LVSFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "DFW") {
                DFWFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "JNB") {
                JNBFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "HND") {
                HNDFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "SVO") {
                SVOFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "LIS") {
                LISFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "MAD") {
                MADFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "RAK") {
                RAKFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "ATH") {
                ATHFlights.add(Flights);

            } else if (Flights.getArrivalAirport() == "FCO") {
                FCOFlights.add(Flights);
            
            }
            if (delayTime >= 30) {
                LocalTime oldTime = Flights.getArrivalTime();
                // Flights.setArrivalTime(oldTime);formatter.format(today)
                LocalTime newTime = oldTime.plusMinutes(delayTime);/// adds the delayed time
                Flights.setnewArrivalTime(newTime);
                alldelayedFlights.add(Flights);
            }
            }
            
            //........
            //if flightdate .equals date;
            
            
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

            Date today = new Date();
            
            
            
            //System.out.println(formatter.format(today));
            // "2022-03-03"*/
            
            

//          Date todayWithZeroTime = formatter.parse(formatter.format(today));

            
            
            
        }                                                
        myReader.close();// closes the reader
        //for(int i = 0; i < allFlights.size();i++)
        ///{
            ///System.out.println(allFlights.get(i).getdepartureCity() + " " +allFlights.get(i).getdepartureAirport() + " " + allFlights.get(i).getFlightNo() + " delayed by " + allFlights.get(i).getdelayedTime() + " minutes") ;
            
        
            
            
        ///}
        for(int i = 0; i < alldelayedFlights.size();i++)///for the length of the array list delayed flights
        {
            //System.out.println(alldelayedFlights.get(i).getdepartureTime() + " " +alldelayedFlights.get(i).getdepartureAirport() + " " + alldelayedFlights.get(i).getArrivalAirport() + " " + alldelayedFlights.get(i).getArrivalTime() + " " + alldelayedFlights.get(i).getdelayedTime() + " " + alldelayedFlights.get(i).getnewArrivalTime() + " " + alldelayedFlights.get(i).getFlightDate())  ;
            
    
        }
        
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File cannot be found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    
    
    }
```

In another GUI java program I have used the pop up method to show a window depending on which airport I click on.

```
lblNewLabel_11 = new JLabel("HND");
        lblNewLabel_11.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_11.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_11.setBounds(817, 277, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_11);
        
        lblNewLabel_12 = new JLabel("SYD");
        lblNewLabel_12.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_12.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_12.setBounds(855, 503, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_12);
        
        lblNewLabel_13 = new JLabel("JNB");
        lblNewLabel_13.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

Below is the UI file which uses window builder to build a UI

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private JLabel lblMad;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_2;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_3;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_4;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_5;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_6;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_7;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_8;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_9;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_10;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_11;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_12;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_13;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_14;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_15;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_16;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_17;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_18;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_19;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_20;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_21;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_22;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_23;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_24;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_25;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BCLAirport.mainrun();
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1351, 770);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        lblNewLabel_18 = new JLabel("DFW");
        lblNewLabel_18.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_18.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_18.setBounds(105, 290, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_18);
        
        lblNewLabel_16 = new JLabel("LVS");
        lblNewLabel_16.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_16.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_16.setBounds(52, 267, 55, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_16);
        
        lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("YYZ\r\n");
        lblNewLabel_4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(187, 231, 33, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_4);
        
        lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("DUB");
        lblNewLabel_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(388, 216, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_2);
        
        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("BCL");
        lblNewLabel_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(420, 210, 27, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("JFK");
        lblNewLabel_3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(193, 267, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_3);
        
        lblMad = new JLabel("MAD");
        lblMad.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblMad.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblMad.setBounds(414, 267, 33, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblMad);
        
        lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("LIS");
        lblNewLabel_5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_5.setBounds(383, 267, 21, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_5);
        
        lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("CAI");
        lblNewLabel_6.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_6.setBounds(502, 309, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_6);
        
        lblNewLabel_7 = new JLabel("DXB");
        lblNewLabel_7.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_7.setBounds(569, 321, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_7);
        
        lblNewLabel_8 = new JLabel("DEL");
        lblNewLabel_8.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_8.setBounds(647, 309, 21, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_8);
        
        lblNewLabel_9 = new JLabel("BKK");
        lblNewLabel_9.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_9.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_9.setBounds(727, 343, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_9);
        
        lblNewLabel_10 = new JLabel("HKG");
        lblNewLabel_10.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_10.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_10.setBounds(756, 309, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_10);
        
        lblNewLabel_11 = new JLabel("HND");
        lblNewLabel_11.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_11.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_11.setBounds(817, 277, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_11);
        
        lblNewLabel_12 = new JLabel("SYD");
        lblNewLabel_12.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_12.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_12.setBounds(855, 503, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_12);
        
        lblNewLabel_13 = new JLabel("JNB");
        lblNewLabel_13.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_13.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_13.setBounds(484, 503, 21, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_13);
        
        lblNewLabel_14 = new JLabel("LOS");
        lblNewLabel_14.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_14.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_14.setBounds(433, 371, 21, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_14);
        
        lblNewLabel_15 = new JLabel("RAK");
        lblNewLabel_15.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_15.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_15.setBounds(381, 290, 34, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_15);
        
        lblNewLabel_17 = new JLabel("GRU");
        lblNewLabel_17.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_17.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_17.setBounds(264, 480, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_17);
        
        lblNewLabel_19 = new JLabel("MEX");
        lblNewLabel_19.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_19.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_19.setBounds(93, 321, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_19);
        
        lblNewLabel_20 = new JLabel("ATH");
        lblNewLabel_20.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_20.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_20.setBounds(478, 267, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_20);
        
        lblNewLabel_21 = new JLabel("CDG");
        lblNewLabel_21.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_21.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_21.setBounds(420, 244, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_21);
        
        lblNewLabel_22 = new JLabel("ARN");
        lblNewLabel_22.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_22.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_22.setBounds(453, 186, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_22);
        
        lblNewLabel_23 = new JLabel("AMS");
        lblNewLabel_23.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_23.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_23.setBounds(453, 216, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_23);
        
        lblNewLabel_24 = new JLabel("SVO");
        lblNewLabel_24.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_24.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_24.setBounds(520, 216, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_24);
        
        lblNewLabel_25 = new JLabel("FCO");
        lblNewLabel_25.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        lblNewLabel_25.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel_25.setBounds(453, 255, 27, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_25);
        
        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Map(don't delete)");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 130, 944, 469);
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Student\\Pictures\\GUI\\map.png"));
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(970, 133, 334, 571);
        contentPane.add(textArea);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setBounds(970, 133, 334, 571);
        contentPane.add(scroll);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("LVS");
        lblMad.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Popup frame = new Popup();
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(52, 263, 45, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_26 = new JLabel("Delayed Flights");
        lblNewLabel_26.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 21));
        lblNewLabel_26.setBounds(1034, 72, 189, 51);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_26);
        
        for (Flights f:BCLAirport.alldelayedFlights )
        {
            textArea.append(f.getdepartureTime() + " " +f.getdepartureAirport() + " " + f.getArrivalAirport() + " " + f.getArrivalTime() + " " + f.getdelayedTime() + " " + f.getnewArrivalTime() + " " + f.getFlightDate() + "\n" );//prints the results and goes to a new line
            
        }
    }
}
```

The main issue I have having is working out how to implement a way to show the incoming flightArrivals for each airport depending on which aiport I click for a reference see the picture for how the airport UI looks[Here's UI normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLaoK.png)

When I hover on the name of an airport at the moment blank window pops up but I want it to show the incoming arrivals for the day. I have been able to show delayedFlights but have been unable to show the specific arraylists for each airport which I want to show in the format
ArrivalTime, Departure City, Departure Airport, FlightNo

It should look like this when you hover on a airport name[How it should ideally look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJdo.png)

If someone could help that would be great becaus I'm quite stuck

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your issue? Is it that you only see delayed flights but not all flights? You have `static ArrayList<Flights> allFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>();` but as far as I see you never add a flight to it. You only add flights to the other lists.

Unrelated to your main issue, but some general observations:

- Consider renaming `Flights` to `Flight` This class is a single flight, not a list of flights right?
- You have an `ArrayList<Flight>` for every airport. This seems really difficult to work with. Maybe there is a different data structure that better fits your needs. Maybe `Map<Airport, List<Flight>> flightsByAirport`
- It looks like each airport is it's own class? `BCLAirport` Maybe there is a different way to handle that.